# a list of multiple lists of 2 for synonyms

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I want to read the synonyms from a csv file , where the first word is the "main" word and the rest of the words in the same record are its synonyms
[image]

now i basically want to create a list like i would have in R ,

```
**synonyms <- list(
  list(word="ss", syns=c("yy","yyss")),
  list(word="ser", syns=c("sert","sertyy","serty"))
)**
```

This gives me a list as

```
synonyms
[[1]]
[[1]]$word
[1] "ss"

[[1]]$syns
[1] "yy"   "yyss"


[[2]]
[[2]]$word
[1] "ser"

[[2]]$syns
[1] "sert"   "sertyy" "serty"
```

which is essentially a list of lists of "word" and "syns". 
how do i go about creating the similar list while reading the word and synonyms from a csv file

any pointers would help !! Thanks

Comment: I would look into `readLines`. This will return a vector where each element is a line of the csv. You can then do parsing with `strsplit` to get a list of vectors fwhere the first element of each vector is your word and the remainder are the the synonyms.

Comment: i am able to do this but then how do i convert the first element of the vector to the first element of the list(named $word) and the subsequent words as the 2nd element of the list in the form of a char vector (named $syns)

Comment: Here is a reproducible example. In the future, please produce an example for use to work with. Images of data are not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process should return what you want.

```
# read in data using readLines
myStuff <- readLines(textConnection(temp))
```

This will return a character vector with one element per line in the file. Note that `textConnection` is not necessary for reading in files. Just supply the file path. Now, split each vector element into a vectors using `strsplit` and return a list.

```
myList <- strsplit(myStuff, split=" ")
```

Now, separate the first element from the remaining element for each vector within the list.

```
result <- lapply(myList, function(x) list(word=x[1], synonyms=x[-1]))
```

This returns the desired result. We use `lapply` to move through the list items. For each list item, we return a named list where the first element, named word, corresponds to the first element of the vector that is the list item and the remaining elements of this vector are placed in a second list element called synonyms.

```
result
[[1]]
[[1]]$word
[1] "ss"

[[1]]$synonyms
[1] "yy"   "yyss"


[[2]]
[[2]]$word
[1] "ser"

[[2]]$synonyms
[1] "sert"   "sertyy" "serty" 


[[3]]
[[3]]$word
[1] "at"

[[3]]$synonyms
[1] "ate"  "ater" "ates"


[[4]]
[[4]]$word
[1] "late"

[[4]]$synonyms
[1] "lated" "lates" "latee"
```

**data**

```
temp <- 
"ss yy yyss
ser sert sertyy serty
at ate ater ates
late lated lates latee"
```